# Getting 404 error when trying to access Laravel app using laravel artisan command on some apps

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-artisan, laravel-valet

I have two APIs A & B, A is my core app and they both communicate on a DB level.
Both run on Ubuntu 22.04, firewall is disable.

When I run php artisan on the API A, I can access it from the web browser and it successfuly display Laravel welcome page using this URL & prot 127.0.0.1:5000 and same with postman.

But when I run the same command after stopping the server on API B, I get the following

```
{"error":"The specified URL cannot be found","code":404}
```

And in postman the request always hang when try log into the API.

I really don't know what is going on, I was expecting a 500 error but not 404.

Both APIs work on the live server, the issue happen on my local machine.

Note that API A is compatible with both php7.4 & php8.1, API B has php8 synthax so I running both using php8.1 and I setting php version using Laravel valet with nginx.

Also note that when I try to login with postman after running

```
php artisan serve --port=5000 // API A
```

Then

```
php artisan server --port=5001 // API B
```

I can login with **API A**, but But the server hang with **API B**
When I stopped it, and try to run it again *API B command*, it says port already in use

I try switching port, still getting the same 404 error on API B, I espect it to display Laravel welcome page as with the API A.

Comment: I honestly have no idea, but please, switch to Docker, either use Laravel Sail, or just your own docker, there are plenty of resources on how to setup both, it will help you a lot!

Comment: I have been struggling with this for quite sometime, API B is the only site having that issue, both API hare using laravel 8, but all my site work fine with the command, I feel more comfortable with Laravel-valet for now, but the issue here php artisan serve command, I not sure using docker will solve the issue but I will try that, thanks.